# NextJS generateMetadata does not provide correct params

Tags: reactjs, next.js, seo, next.js13

generateMetadata provides `params` as it does for a page. I need to fetch metadata from my CMS, using `lang` and `slug` from these params. They are always undefined and fallback to defaults.

```
export async function generateMetadata(params: { slug: string, lang: string }): Promise<Metadata> {
    const response = await fetchStrapiPageLayout(params.slug ?? '/', params.lang)
    return {
        title: response.seo_title,
        description: response.seo_description,
        keywords: response.seo_keywords,
    }
}
```

Now, the weirdest part is having some console logs in there.
[image]

I expect the params to have correct information, but it does not happen

Answer (score 1):

- write async logic in `try/catch` to catch if there is an error
- also in case of error return something general

  ```
  export async function generateMetadata(
    params: { slug: string, lang: string }): Promise<Metadata> {
  try {
    const response = await fetchStrapiPageLayout(params.slug ?? '/', params.lang)

    return {
      title: response ? response.seo_title : "SetDefaultTitle",
      description: response?.seo_description,
      keywords: response.seo_keywords,
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return {
      title: "Not Found",
      description: "The page you are looking for does not exist",
    };
  }}
  ```